# Javascript runtime error using IE11 on Win7: Unable to set property 'disabled' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-7, internet-explorer-11

I am currently working on some IE11 compatibility issues. The code is fully functional in compatibility mode as it was previously optimize last for IE5.

The affected code is as follows:

```
/*
 * This function sets the specified button state in the repair processing form
 */
function setOperationButton(buttonId, disabledState, sourceImage, styleCursor)
{
    var buttonElement = document.frmRepairProcessing.elements[buttonId];
    var sourceRoot = '<%=helper.getApplicationURL()%>' + '/zimages/' + '<%=localeString%>' + '/';
    buttonElement.disabled = disabledState;
    buttonElement.src = sourceRoot + sourceImage;
    buttonElement.style.cursor = styleCursor;   
}
```

So I am thinking the code simply needs to be updated to use getElementById, but I am not quite sure how to implement the specific form.

Please note: I have also tried document.forms().elements() and using .value as well.

Comment: You should try `document.forms()[FORM_NAME].elements() `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it will be acceptable to use below code to obtain buttonElement:

```
function setOperationButton(buttonId, disabledState, sourceImage, styleCursor)
{
    var buttonElement = document.getElementById(buttonId);
    var sourceRoot = '<%=helper.getApplicationURL()%>' + '/zimages/' + '<%=localeString%>' + '/';
    buttonElement.disabled = disabledState;
    buttonElement.src = sourceRoot + sourceImage;
    buttonElement.style.cursor = styleCursor;   
}
```

Comment: Thought it necessary to implement the form as well.. But simply 'document.getElementById(buttonId)' worked. Thank you! :)